# what is the alternative in harmonyos for TypedValue.applyDimension(int unit, float value, android.util.DisplayMetrics metrics)?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am writing a custom component in HarmonyOS using Java SDK.

I am trying to convert vp to Px.

In Android we can convert dp to px using below code.

```
TypedValue.applyDimension(
                        int unit,
                        float value,
                        android.util.DisplayMetrics metrics)
```

I tried the following code for HarmonyOS but not working.

```
TypedAttribute.computeTranslateRatio(DeviceCapability devCap)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try method `AttrHelper.vp2px`. doc: https://developer.harmonyos.com/cn/docs/documentation/doc-references/attrhelper-0000001054518726

Comment: I found one more solution, we can do also like this:

`public static int dp2px(float dp) {
        return (int) (dp * TypedAttribute.computeTranslateRatio(new DeviceCapability()));
    }`