# How much 1px is with respect to fp in Harmony OS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

Can anyone tell **px:fp** ratio or code to convert fp to px. 
I am building a HarmonyOS application and I want to set the width of a component to 20fp but `setWidth​(int width)` takes width in px.

```
Button button = new Button(getContext());
button.setWidth(width);
```

Comment: Try method `AttrHelper.fp2px`. doc: https://developer.harmonyos.com/cn/docs/documentation/doc-references/attrhelper-0000001054518726 similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68542357/what-is-the-alternative-in-harmonyos-for-typedvalue-applydimensionint-unit-flo/68555697#68555697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HarmonyOS provides the `AttrHelper` tool class to implement conversion between fp and px.

`AttrHelper.fp2px()`

For more details, pls kindly refer to this [Docs](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/attrhelper-0000001054518726).